# AVLTree java rotations not working properly. I am only trying to implement left rotation and then go from there

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

Im having trouble rotating a Tree and returning the rotated Tree. Pretty much after inserting a new Tree to my AVL I check for the balance if it is <-1 and the parent height is <0 the it is a right right case and I need to implement a left rotation. I need help understanding why my left rotation is not working and if it working why I do not get in return the rotated Tree.

```
public class AVLTree < T extends Comparable < T >> extends BinaryTree < T> 
{

private int balance ;

private AVLTree < T> parent;


public AVLTree(T item){

  this(item,null);
}
public AVLTree(T item, AVLTree<T> parent){
  super(item);
  this.balance = 0;
  this.parent = parent;    
}

public AVLTree<T> insert(T item){
  updateHeight(this);   
  if(this.item.compareTo(item) < 0){
 if(this.left != null){     
        this.left.insert(item);
 }
  else{

    this.left= new AVLTree<T>(item, this);

  }
  return rotations((AVLTree<T>)this.left);
  }
  else{
 if(this.right != null){
        this.right.insert(item);
 }
 else{
    this.right = new AVLTree<T>(item, this);        
 }
 return rotations((AVLTree<T>)this.right);
  } 
}  


private AVLTree<T> rotateLeft(AVLTree<T> x){

AVLTree<T> temp = (AVLTree<T>)x.parent;
AVLTree<T> an = (AVLTree<T>)temp.left;          

//rotation
temp.left = x;
temp.right = x.parent.right;
x.right = an;

//update heights
updateHeight(x);
updateHeight(temp);

//return new root
return temp;
}


public AVLTree<T> rotations(AVLTree<T> input){
  int balance = getBalance(input);
//Right Right
if (balance < -1 && ph() < 0){
   return input =rotateLeft(input);
}
return input;
}


public void updateHeight(AVLTree<T> current){
  current.height = Math.max(height((AVLTree<T>)current.left), 
height((AVLTree<T>)current.right)) + 1;
}
public int getBalance(){
  return getBalance(this);
}
public int getBalance(AVLTree<T> current){
  return (current == null)? 0 : height((AVLTree<T>)current.right) -  
  height((AVLTree<T>)current.left);
}
public int ph(){
  return lbal()-rbal();
}

int lbal(){
  if(this.right== null){
     return 0;
  }   
  return (height(this.right));
}
int rbal(){
   if(this.left == null){
      return 0;
   }
  return height(this.left);
}
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Here is the BST class

```
import java.util.*;
public class BinaryTree <T extends Comparable<T>> extends Tree<Comparable<T>>{

public BinaryTree<T> left;
public BinaryTree<T> right;
int size;
int height;

public BinaryTree(T item){
   super(item);
   this.item = item;
   this.left = null;
   this.right= null; 
}

public BinaryTree<T> find(T item){
   if(this.item.compareTo(item)==0){
      return this;
}
   if(this.item.compareTo(item)<0){
      if(this.left != null){
         if(this.left.item.compareTo(item) == 0){
            return this.left;
         }
         else{
            return this.left.find(item);

         }
      }     
   }

   else{
      if(this.right != null){
         if(this.right.item.compareTo(item) == 0){
            return this.right;
         }
         else{  
            return this.right.find(item);
         }
      }   
   }
   return null;      
}
public BinaryTree<T> insert(T item){
   if(this.item.compareTo(item) < 0){
      if(this.left != null){     
        this.left.insert(item);
 }
  else{
    this.left = new BinaryTree<T>(item);

  }
  return this.left;
  }
  else{
 if(this.right != null){
        this.right.insert(item);
 }
 else{
    this.right = new BinaryTree<T>(item);

 }
 return this.right;
  }
```

}

//part 4 measurment

```
public int size(){
   return size(this);

}

public int size(BinaryTree<T> point){
  if(point == null){
     return 0;
  }
  else{
     return (size(point.left)+1+size(point.right));
  }
}
/*
*public int height() {
  height = 1;
  if (left != null) {
    height += left.height;
  }
  if (right != null) {
    height += right.height;
  }
  return height;
}
*
* */
public int height(){
  return height(this);
}
public int height(BinaryTree<T> point) {
  if(point == null){
     return 0;
  }
  return (Math.max(height(point.right), height(point.left))+1);
 }

//Part 3

public ArrayList<T> nlr(){
  return nlr(this);
}
private ArrayList<T> nlr(BinaryTree<T> point){
  ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
  if (point == null){
     return arr;
  }
  arr.add(point.item);
  arr.addAll(nlr(point.left));
  arr.addAll(nlr(point.right));
  return arr;
}

public ArrayList<T> lnr(){
  return lnr(this);
}
private ArrayList<T> lnr(BinaryTree<T> point){
  ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
  if (point == null){
     return arr;
  }
  arr.addAll(lnr(point.left));
  arr.add(point.item);
  arr.addAll(lnr(point.right));
  return arr;
}

public ArrayList<T> lrn(){
  return lrn(this);
}
private ArrayList<T> lrn(BinaryTree<T> point){
  ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
  if (point == null){
     return arr;
  }
  arr.addAll(lrn(point.left));
  arr.addAll(lrn(point.right));
  arr.add(point.item);
  return arr;
}

public ArrayList<T> bfs(){
  return bfs(this);
}
private ArrayList<T> bfs(BinaryTree<T> input){
  Queue<BinaryTree> queue = new LinkedList<BinaryTree>();
  ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
  queue.add(input);
  while(!queue.isEmpty()){
     input = queue.remove();
 arr.add(input.item);
 if(input.left != null){
    queue.add(input.left);
 }
 if(input.right != null){
    queue.add(input.right);
 }
  }
  return arr;
}

public BinaryTree<T> rotateLeft(){
  return null;
}
public BinaryTree<T> rotateRight(){
  return null;
}


}
```

Comment: Firstly, please consider formatting your code with proper indentation. As it stands it's quite difficult to read. Second, what have you done to troubleshoot the code? Have you tried adding break points in your IDE to step through your code to see where it's failing? Or perhaps you've tried printing out debugging statements. Lastly, you mentioned not getting the rotated tree as a return value (perhaps from the `AVLTree<T> insert(T item)` method). What are you getting in return instead?

Comment: Sorry about the Indentation I just copy and paste the code from my editor to here. Pretty much when I use my breadth search I get a regular BST not an AVLtree so pretty much the insertions happened without a single rotation.

Comment: Hmm, you may need to add the code for `BinaryTree` for us to get the full picture. `BinaryTree` should be completely unaware of `AVLTree`, so if the breadth search function is implemented in `BinaryTree`, it can never return an `AVLTree`. As a general rule, if you find yourself type-casting, as in `return rotations((AVLTree<T>)this.left)`, no offense but there's a good chance you're misusing object-oriented programming; there's probably a class/interface with too much responsibility.

Comment: No offense taken but the project ask us to extend a Binary Tree to AVL

Comment: Yeah... sometimes school and the real-world don't line up. OK, well go ahead and add your `BinaryTree` implementation.

Comment: Sorry about the late reply

Answer (score 1):

One thing I noticed for this rotation.
For a Rotate left you are rotating the Right subtree up for a correct rotation

```
//rotation
temp.left = x; 
//this is making the right child now the left child of the parent.
temp.right = x.parent.right;  
//this is making the same right sub tree copied to the left 
//which needs to be rotated the child of the right side as well which it 
//should already be.(does nothing)
x.right = an;  
//making this a right child(without check if there is a node) of the right 
//subtree.
//So this is in actuality not doing a correct rotation for an AVL tree.
```

please replace above code with:

```
AVLTree<T> temp1 = (AVLTree<T>)x.parent;


temp1.right = x.left;  
//make the left node of the right subtree the new right node of the parent
x.left = temp1;
//make the current parent the left child of the right subtree(rotation).
x.parent = temp1.parent;
//make the parent of the right subtree point to the parent of the parent
//keeping tree integrity.
temp1.parent = x;
//make the parent pointer to what used to be the right child.   
//this completes a single left rotation for an AVL tree.
return x;
//the node that is now the parent node of the rotated subtree 
//or the new root node. if the rotation happened at the top.
```

Please check 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree
for a full explanation and how the AVL tree works with all rotations with code clips for single and double rotations.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the search functionality, `BinaryTree<T> find(T item)` is implemented in the parent class `BinaryTree`, and this class, as it should, doesn't have any knowledge of the subclass `AVLTree`.

The `find()` method returns a `BinaryTree`, so even if you construct an instance of `AVLTree`, when you call `find()` you will get a `BinaryTree`.

Assuming the `AVLTree<T> insert(T item)` implementation is correct, the tree nodes are being assembled correctly, so you can simply type-cast the result of calling `find()` to an `AVLTree`